# onChange or onBlur to change the state in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, onchange, onblur

//Assume am changing `state` in `handleChange` function.

In case of `onChange` event state will update every character change.

```
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    id="name"
  />
```

In case of `onBlur` event state will update at single shot after leaving input fields.

```
 <input
   type="text"
   name="name"
   onBlur={this.handleChange}
   id="name"
 />
```

which approach is best to update the `state` in `React` and why ?

Comment: without reading any answers, I am going to say onChange. I went down the onBlur route and because I am connecting invalid fields to enabling/disabling a button, it makes more sense for the user to see the button being enabled as they type rather than when they leave the field.

Answer (score 15):

*This is actually a trade-off decision.*

I assume that, in your event handler function, you are calling `React setState()` to update your states.

A call to setState is asynchronous. It creates a "pending state transition." (See [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) for more details). It is really fast and has a reducer to update only changed nodes. So you really don't need to think about performance.

- Choose `onChange()`: If you need the latest state immediately after input change, for example:

> Search suggestion after each input (like Google search box)
>
> Validating input after every change

- Choose `onBlur()`: If you only need the latest state at the end of the final input, for example:

> Every change triggers a fetch event that checks if entered username or email exists

---

**Also think of this scenario:**

The end-user filled all 3 registration inputs (name, password and email), but after the last input i.e. email, s/he directly clicked the send button (which has fired your signup method without the updated email value/state).

Since `setState` is asynchronous and has not updated the email state yet, you might face problems about null email inputs.

So, my unofficial suggestion is to use `onChange` whenever possible and use `onBlur` only when you need final changed value.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose either of methods based on your requirement.

For example, if you need to perform validations to a field while the input is being entered ,  you could choose onChange.

Setting the state with onChange would be called every-time you enter something to field which leads to re-render the input again.

onBlur would call the setState only when you focus-out the input.

In my Opinion, onBlur would be good option , but it totally depends on the requirement which we have.